# Lodash at() method does not work in ts file (works in .js)

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am converting all my .js files to .ts

I am using lodash `at()`

```
{ 
  data:
      {
          test: 'test',
          sample: 'sample'
      }
}
```

sample.js:

```
var test = _.at(res[0], 'data.sample');
console.log(test);
```

output:

```
'sample'
```

sample.ts:

```
let test = _.at(res[0], 'data.sample');

// error: Argument of type '"data.sample"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Many<"constructor" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "valueOf" | "hasOwnProperty" | "isPrototypeO...'.
```

Cannot use `at()` in .ts file as used in .js file

Answer (score 1):

The method [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#at) expects an array of strings according to the documentation. Using a single string actually works, but it's not documented, and might not be supported by all `@types/lodash` versions. A simple solution would be.

```
_.at(res[0], ['data.sample']);
```

However, since you need only one item, [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) is a better option:

```
_.get(res[0], 'data.sample');
```